# How to build Caffe library on Windows (Visual Studio 2013)?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, caffe

have anyone successfully using Caffe library in Visual Studio development? If yes, can you make a short overview (step by step).

What I've already done:
 - download Caffe from Github
 - building Boost
 - building Cuda Toolkit 7.5
 - building gflags
 - building glog

Still have to do:
- hdf5
- protobuf
- GLog 
....

Have anyone any instructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to build and use Caffe on Windows,but if you're insisting on that you can find this perfect step-by-step guide so helpful.

[Build Caffe in Windows with Visual Studio 2013 + CUDA 6.5 + OpenCV 2.4.9](https://initialneil.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/build-caffe-in-windows-with-visual-studio-2013-cuda-6-5-opencv-2-4-9/)

Comment: thanks for answer) 
I want cross-platform application. How can I achive that with caffe(or other deep learning library)? 
I've used this article, but for example I want to compile the newest version of caffe with the newest versions of all dependencies. I should know how to build everything by myself.

Comment: I think that would be so hard by Caffe. I haven't used other frameworks, but take a look at MatConvNet and check whether it is more portable that Caffe or not.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**
Since microsoft [adopted the porting of CAFFE to windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/caffe) , there is now an even easier way to build CAFFE for windows with visual studio. The entire process is depicted in [this 5 min video!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrzAF2sxHHM)

<s>i saw the answer by Saeed, and i think i have something easier to propose.</s>

Follow the built found [here](https://github.com/happynear/caffe-windows) for a very easy build of Caffe on windows. However, you always have to check it for changes, since their code updates regularly, but their documentation stays behind. In my case (and many other co-workers) their code builts as-is, right out of the box!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Collective Knowledge workflow framework to automatically install Caffe on Windows, Linux or MacOS from command line in just a few steps. See

- https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/5654#issuecomment-372123226
- https://github.com/dividiti/ck-caffe

Basically, you just need to do the following:

```
   pip install ck
   ck pull repo --url=https://github.com/dividiti/ck-caffe
   ck install package:lib-caffe-bvlc-master-cudnn-universal --env.CAFFE_BUILD_PYTHON=ON
```

CK will detect or rebuild all necessary dependencies on Windows (HDF5, Boost, OpenCV, etc). You can then use Caffe from virtual environment as follows:

```
   ck show env
   ck virtual env --tags=lib,caffe

   python
   > import caffe
```

Hope it's of any help!